# Misaligning in notification in iPad app

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, badges, ios-app

[image]

All the rep changes or badges shown in the notification are placed in a higher position than the middle. If the notification has only one line, it's misaligned too.

- App Version: 1.4.1.3
- Device: iPad 2 (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.1 (Build 13B143)

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in 1.4.3.1.

The issue was caused by a mix of problematic constraints causing the view to be pinned to 10pt from the top and some layout width code that was required for iOS7 that was no longer needed by iOS8 and breaks things in iOS9.